# Stretching the navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Hi Everyone,**

I am trying to stretch my navigation bar so the links are evenly spaced out the browser window instead of being right next to each other. I would like this to responsive rather than fixed.

**My HTML**

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
           <img src="./images/R_medum.jpg" class="nav-image" alt=""/>
                <div class="navbar-links">
                    <ul> 
                        <li><a href="#" title="There is no place like it">127.0.0.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://google.com">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> YouTube </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div> 
        </div>
```

**My CSS**

```
.navbar-wrapper {
  width:100%;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}

.navbar-wrapper img {
  float: left;
}

#navbar {
   margin: 0; 
   padding: .3em 0 .3em 0; 
   display: inline;
   float: left;
 }


 .navbar-links ul {
   list-style: none; 
   margin: 50px; 
   padding: 0; 
   display: table;
   float: left;
   text-align: justify;
   width: calc(10% -115px);

 }



 .navbar-links li { 
   vertical-align: center; 
   padding: 0; 
   display: table-cell; 
   text-align: center;
   float: left;
   white-space: nowrap;
   width: calc(calc(100 - 115px) / 4);

} 

.navbar-links ul a{ 
   margin: 0; 
   padding: .3em .4em .3em .4em; 
   text-decoration: none; 
   font-weight: bold; 
   font-size: 1.5em; 
   background-color: black; 
   color: orange;
} 



.navbar-links ul a:visited{ 
   margin: 0; 
   padding: .3em .4em .3em .4em; 
   text-decoration: none; 
   font-weight: bold;
   font-style: italic; 
   font-size: 1.5em; 
   color: green; 
} 

.navbar-links ul a:active{ 
   margin: 0; 
   padding: .3em .4em .3em .4em; 
   text-decoration: none; 
   font-weight: bold; 
   font-size: medium; 
   color: white; 
} 


.navbar-links ul a:hover{ 
   margin: 0; 
   padding: .3em .4em .3em .4em; 
   text-decoration: none; 
   font-weight: bold; 
   font-size: 1.8em; 
   color: #f6f0cc; 
   background-color: #227755; 
}
```

**What I have tried**

I have tried almost everything. I achieved this behavior with adjusting the padding settings however this obviously is not uniform across window sizes. Also I saw a solution that set the navbar-links to table, the ***ul*** element to table-row & the ***li*** element to table-cell however this did not work in my case and Im not sure why.

How can this behavior be achieved ?

**JSFIDDLE**
https://jsfiddle.net/uoxgLvbL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were on the right track with table/table cell, you were just a little off.

What I'm doing here is treating the logo and nav as a table/table-cell, then treating the nav ul itself also as a table/table-cell.

Be sure when using table/table-cell, not to use floats which will render it all useless.

Instead of treating the image, I created a div around the image to achieve the needs:

```
 <div class="navbar-wrapper">
    <div class="nav-image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/110x117" class="" alt=""/>
    </div>
         <div class="navbar-links">
           <ul> 
             <li><a href="#" title="There is no place like it">127.0.0.1</a></li>
             <li><a href="https://google.com">About</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
             <li><a href="#"> YouTube </a></li>
          </ul>
      </div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: black;
}

.navbar-wrapper {
  width:100%;
    display:table;
}

.navbar-wrapper img {
    display:block;
}
.nav-image { display:table-cell; }

#navbar {
   margin: 0; 
   padding: .3em 0 .3em 0;  
    display:table-cell;
}

.navbar-links { display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; }

 .navbar-links ul {
   list-style: none; 
   margin:  0; 
   padding: 0; 
   display: table;
   text-align: justify;
   width: 100%;
    height:100%;

 }

 .navbar-links li { 
   vertical-align:top; 
   padding: 0; 
   display: table-cell; 
   text-align: center;
   white-space: nowrap;

}
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/uoxgLvbL/1/)

With some media queries:

https://jsfiddle.net/uoxgLvbL/2/

Comment: Ahh I was soo close. Damn Floats. Thanks StuFu